# Android Hello world Qt 5.2 AVD

Tags: android, qt

The AVD starts up fine but then I run into problems. I get the same result from any of the other AVDs that I start up as well. Any ideas?

Seems like every step I make forward takes me back many steps. Not that is matters but I'm running this on Windows 8 - 64 bit, Qt 5.2

```
 Starting remote process.W/dalvikvm( 1040): PR_CAPBSET_DROP 0 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
W/dalvikvm( 1040): PR_CAPBSET_DROP 1 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
W/dalvikvm( 1040): PR_CAPBSET_DROP 2 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
W/dalvikvm( 1040): PR_CAPBSET_DROP 3 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
W/dalvikvm( 1040): PR_CAPBSET_DROP 4 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
W/dalvikvm( 1040): PR_CAPBSET_DROP 5 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
W/dalvikvm( 1040): PR_CAPBSET_DROP 6 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
W/dalvikvm( 1040): PR_CAPBSET_DROP 7 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
W/dalvikvm( 1040): PR_CAPBSET_DROP 8 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
W/dalvikvm( 1040): PR_CAPBSET_DROP 9 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
W/dalvikvm( 1040): PR_CAPBSET_DROP 10 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
W/dalvikvm( 1040): PR_CAPBSET_DROP 11 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
W/dalvikvm( 1040): PR_CAPBSET_DROP 12 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
W/dalvikvm( 1040): PR_CAPBSET_DROP 13 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
W/dalvikvm( 1040): PR_CAPBSET_DROP 14 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
W/dalvikvm( 1040): PR_CAPBSET_DROP 15 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
W/dalvikvm( 1040): PR_CAPBSET_DROP 16 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
W/dalvikvm( 1040): PR_CAPBSET_DROP 17 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
W/dalvikvm( 1040): PR_CAPBSET_DROP 18 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
W/dalvikvm( 1040): PR_CAPBSET_DROP 19 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
W/dalvikvm( 1040): PR_CAPBSET_DROP 20 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
W/dalvikvm( 1040): PR_CAPBSET_DROP 21 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
W/dalvikvm( 1040): PR_CAPBSET_DROP 22 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
W/dalvikvm( 1040): PR_CAPBSET_DROP 23 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
W/dalvikvm( 1040): PR_CAPBSET_DROP 24 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
W/dalvikvm( 1040): PR_CAPBSET_DROP 25 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
W/dalvikvm( 1040): PR_CAPBSET_DROP 26 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
W/dalvikvm( 1040): PR_CAPBSET_DROP 27 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
W/dalvikvm( 1040): PR_CAPBSET_DROP 28 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
W/dalvikvm( 1040): PR_CAPBSET_DROP 29 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
W/dalvikvm( 1040): PR_CAPBSET_DROP 30 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
W/dalvikvm( 1040): PR_CAPBSET_DROP 31 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
W/dalvikvm( 1040): PR_CAPBSET_DROP 32 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
W/dalvikvm( 1040): PR_CAPBSET_DROP 33 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
D/dalvikvm( 1040): Not late-enabling CheckJNI (already on)
D/dalvikvm( 1040): GC_CONCURRENT freed 229K, 12% free 2671K/3020K, paused 6ms+2ms, total 66ms
D/dalvikvm( 1040): GC_CONCURRENT freed 332K, 15% free 2732K/3184K, paused 4ms+3ms, total 38ms
D/dalvikvm( 1040): Trying to load lib /data/data/org.qtproject.example.untitled/lib/libgnustl_shared.so 0x416f38d0
D/dalvikvm( 1040): Added shared lib /data/data/org.qtproject.example.untitled/lib/libgnustl_shared.so 0x416f38d0
D/dalvikvm( 1040): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/data/org.qtproject.example.untitled/lib/libgnustl_shared.so 0x416f38d0, skipping init
D/dalvikvm( 1040): Trying to load lib /data/data/org.qtproject.example.untitled/lib/libQt5Core.so 0x416f38d0
D/dalvikvm( 1040): Added shared lib /data/data/org.qtproject.example.untitled/lib/libQt5Core.so 0x416f38d0
D/dalvikvm( 1040): Trying to load lib /data/data/org.qtproject.example.untitled/lib/libQt5Network.so 0x416f38d0
D/dalvikvm( 1040): Added shared lib /data/data/org.qtproject.example.untitled/lib/libQt5Network.so 0x416f38d0
I/Qt      ( 1040): Network start
D/dalvikvm( 1040): Trying to load lib /data/data/org.qtproject.example.untitled/lib/libQt5Qml.so 0x416f38d0
D/dalvikvm( 1040): Added shared lib /data/data/org.qtproject.example.untitled/lib/libQt5Qml.so 0x416f38d0
D/dalvikvm( 1040): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/data/org.qtproject.example.untitled/lib/libQt5Qml.so 0x416f38d0, skipping init
D/dalvikvm( 1040): Trying to load lib /data/data/org.qtproject.example.untitled/lib/libQt5Gui.so 0x416f38d0
D/dalvikvm( 1040): Added shared lib /data/data/org.qtproject.example.untitled/lib/libQt5Gui.so 0x416f38d0
D/dalvikvm( 1040): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/data/org.qtproject.example.untitled/lib/libQt5Gui.so 0x416f38d0, skipping init
D/dalvikvm( 1040): Trying to load lib /data/data/org.qtproject.example.untitled/lib/libQt5Quick.so 0x416f38d0
D/dalvikvm( 1040): Added shared lib /data/data/org.qtproject.example.untitled/lib/libQt5Quick.so 0x416f38d0
D/dalvikvm( 1040): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/data/org.qtproject.example.untitled/lib/libQt5Quick.so 0x416f38d0, skipping init
D/dalvikvm( 1040): Trying to load lib /data/data/org.qtproject.example.untitled/lib/libQt5QuickParticles.so 0x416f38d0
D/dalvikvm( 1040): Added shared lib /data/data/org.qtproject.example.untitled/lib/libQt5QuickParticles.so 0x416f38d0
D/dalvikvm( 1040): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/data/org.qtproject.example.untitled/lib/libQt5QuickParticles.so 0x416f38d0, skipping init
D/dalvikvm( 1040): Trying to load lib /data/data/org.qtproject.example.untitled/lib/libQt5Widgets.so 0x416f38d0
D/dalvikvm( 1040): Added shared lib /data/data/org.qtproject.example.untitled/lib/libQt5Widgets.so 0x416f38d0
D/dalvikvm( 1040): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/data/org.qtproject.example.untitled/lib/libQt5Widgets.so 0x416f38d0, skipping init
D/dalvikvm( 1040): Trying to load lib /data/data/org.qtproject.example.untitled/qt-reserved-files/plugins/platforms/android/libqtforandroidGL.so 0x416f38d0
D/dalvikvm( 1040): Added shared lib /data/data/org.qtproject.example.untitled/qt-reserved-files/plugins/platforms/android/libqtforandroidGL.so 0x416f38d0
I/Qt      ( 1040): qt start
D/dalvikvm( 1040): Trying to load lib /data/data/org.qtproject.example.untitled/lib/libQt5QuickParticles.so 0x416f38d0
D/dalvikvm( 1040): Shared lib '/data/data/org.qtproject.example.untitled/lib/libQt5QuickParticles.so' already loaded in same CL 0x416f38d0
D/dalvikvm( 1040): Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/org.qtproject.example.untitled-1/libuntitled.so 0x416f38d0
D/Qt      ( 1040): qml\qqmlengine.cpp:1446 (QQmlDebuggingEnabler::QQmlDebuggingEnabler(bool)): QML debugging is enabled. Only use this in a safe environment.
D/dalvikvm( 1040): Added shared lib /data/app-lib/org.qtproject.example.untitled-1/libuntitled.so 0x416f38d0
D/dalvikvm( 1040): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/app-lib/org.qtproject.example.untitled-1/libuntitled.so 0x416f38d0, skipping init
D/dalvikvm( 1040): GC_CONCURRENT freed 428K, 17% free 2705K/3252K, paused 4ms+35ms, total 81ms
I/Choreographer( 1040): Skipped 68 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
D/gralloc_goldfish( 1040): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
D/libEGL  ( 1040): Emulator without GPU support detected. Fallback to software renderer.
D/libEGL  ( 1040): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLES_android.so
W/Qt      ( 1040): eglconvenience\qeglconvenience.cpp:289 (void* QEglConfigChooser::chooseConfig()): Cant find EGLConfig, returning null config
W/Qt      ( 1040): eglconvenience\qeglconvenience.cpp:289 (void* QEglConfigChooser::chooseConfig()): Cant find EGLConfig, returning null config
W/Qt      ( 1040): scenegraph\qsgcontext.cpp:438 (virtual void QSGRenderContext::initialize(QOpenGLContext*)): QSGContext::initialize: depth buffer support missing, expect rendering errors
W/Qt      ( 1040): scenegraph\qsgcontext.cpp:440 (virtual void QSGRenderContext::initialize(QOpenGLContext*)): QSGContext::initialize: stencil buffer support missing, expect rendering errors
I/ARMAssembler( 1040): generated scanline__00000077:03010108_00000A08_00000000 [  4 ipp] (25 ins) at [0x4cd9e1f0:0x4cd9e254] in 3072555 ns
E/libEGL  ( 1040): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
E/libEGL  ( 1040): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
E/libEGL  ( 1040): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
E/libEGL  ( 1040): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
E/libEGL  ( 1040): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
E/libEGL  ( 1040): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
E/libEGL  ( 1040): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
E/libEGL  ( 1040): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
W/Qt      ( 1040): opengl\qopenglshaderprogram.cpp:319 (bool QOpenGLShaderPrivate::compile(QOpenGLShader*)): QOpenGLShader::compile(Vertex): failed
E/libEGL  ( 1040): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
E/libEGL  ( 1040): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
E/libEGL  ( 1040): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
E/libEGL  ( 1040): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
E/libEGL  ( 1040): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
E/libEGL  ( 1040): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
E/libEGL  ( 1040): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
W/Qt      ( 1040): opengl\qopenglshaderprogram.cpp:319 (bool QOpenGLShaderPrivate::compile(QOpenGLShader*)): QOpenGLShader::compile(Fragment): failed
E/libEGL  ( 1040): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
E/libEGL  ( 1040): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
E/libEGL  ( 1040): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
E/libEGL  ( 1040): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
E/libEGL  ( 1040): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
E/libEGL  ( 1040): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
E/libEGL  ( 1040): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
E/libEGL  ( 1040): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
D/Qt      ( 1040): scenegraph\coreapi\qsgbatchrenderer.cpp:155 (QSGBatchRenderer::ShaderManager::Shader* QSGBatchRenderer::ShaderManager::prepareMaterial(QSGMaterial*)): Renderer failed shader compilation: 
D/Qt      ( 1040): "" 
F/libc    ( 1040): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000008 (code=1), thread 1067 (QSGRenderThread)


"org.qtproject.example.untitled" died.
```

Comment: Looks like your apk doesn't contain a main.py.

Comment: Why would it need a main.py? I have a main.cpp

Comment: I have just solved similar problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24580617/cant-run-application-on-some-android-devices/24696942